# Spelling - why not finanse?

Tags: american-english, orthography

If it is *license* rather than *licence*, *defense* rather than *defence*, *offense* rather than *offence*, then why not *finanse*?

Comment: And conversely, why doesn't British English have _rince_?

Comment: Because language isn't predictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends  on the etymology of each term. 
During centuries of separation from Britain,
American English retained the original -se
ending in certain words borrowed from French, while British English modified it to -ce.

finance (n.): was originally spelt with the suffix '-ce '.

> - c.1400, "an end, settlement, retribution," **from Old French finance** ".

while:

Defence:

> - c.1300, "forbidding, prohibition," also "action of guarding or protecting," from Old **French defense**.

Licence:

> - ," (12c.), from Latin licentia "freedom, liberty, **license,**" "

Offence:

> - late 14c., "hurt, harm, injury, pain," from Old **French ofense**

Source: Etymolnine

Comment: Defense is spelled 'fence' so football fans can make signs consisting of a big D and a picket fence to wave.

Comment: You'd actually expect "licence" to be spelled with a "c" based on etymology alone. Latin "ti" before another vowel  became "c", not "s" in French.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to expect consistency in the use of the spelling *-nse* vs. the spelling *-nce.* The use of *-nce* vs *-nse* is partly, but not entirely based on etymology.

- *License* comes from Latin *licentia,* and *finance* ends in the suffix *-ance* which comes from Latin *-antia* (and partly from *-entia*). *Defense* and *offense* come from Latin *defensa* and *offensa/offensus.*

Here are the etymologically regular developments:

- Latin *-tia* underwent patalatalization and regularly developed to French *-ce.*
- Latin *-sa(m)* regularly developed to French *-se.*
- Latin *-sus/-sum* regularly developed to French *-s.*

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Late_Old_French,_c._1250%E2%80%931300), after the "Late Old French (c. 1250–1300)" time period, *-nce* and *-nse* would have been pronounced identically in French. This seems to have led to non-etymological use of "c" vs. "s" in this context in Middle French.

The OED says that *defense* probably comes from "Anglo-Norman *defens, deffens, diffence,* Anglo-Norman and Middle French *defence, deffence, defense, deffense*". It says that for some reason, the word could be masculine in Anglo-Norman; that presumably is the reason for the Anglo-Norman forms without a final *-e.* You can see that variation between *-nse* and *-nce* spellings existed in the French etymon of the English word.

Similarly, the OED says *offense* is partly from "Anglo-Norman and Middle French *offense, offence*" (and their Latin etymon *offensa*), and partly from "Anglo-Norman and Middle French *offens*" (and their Latin etymon *offensus*).

For *license,* the *-se* spelling seems to have arisen partly from analogy in English. Some noun-verb pairs show an alternation between *-ce* and *-se,* and this probably contributed to the use of the spelling *license* for the English verb. And the use of the *-se* spelling for the verb presumably contributed to or reinforced the use of the *-se* spelling for the noun.

*Finance* can also be a verb, but for some reason, *-se* has not become a recognized variant spelling of this word.